# ffmpeg HLS segmentation audio and video files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to perform HLS segmentation and get audio and video in separated files for each segment from .mp4 video with audio. No need to adapt bitrate, because that will cause an extra delay.

I tried to use

> ffmpeg -i videoInput.mp4 -c:v copy –c:a copy -hls_segment_type mpegts –map a:0 –map v:0 -hls_time 1 out.m3u8 audio.ts

Which generates the video files perfectly but just one audio file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the FFmpeg documentation I understand:

```
       When there are two or more variant streams, the output filename
       pattern must contain the string "%v", this string specifies the
       position of variant stream index in the output media playlist
       filenames. The string "%v" may be present in the filename or in the
       last directory name containing the file. If the string is present
       in the directory name, then sub-directories are created after
       expanding the directory name pattern. This enables creation of
       variant streams in subdirectories.
```

'''

For me:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner  -t 5:00 -i "$IN" -c copy -map a:0 -map v:0  -hls_segment_type mpegts -hls_time 1 -f hls   -var_stream_map "a:0 v:0"    v_%v/file.m3u8
```

creates both streams in v_0 & v_1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact solution, but as a workaround, you can extract the audio first with:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a copy -vn audio.aac
```

Then apply segmentation for video and audio files separately

Audio:

```
 ffmpeg -i audio.aac -c:a copy -hls_segment_type mpegts -map a:0 -hls_time 1 out_aud.m3u8
```

Video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -hls_segment_type mpegts -map v:0 -hls_time 1 out_vid.m3u8
```